# Notice should be compatible with

Tags: php

На сайте выпадают Notice, подскажите пожалуйста как их можно убрать?
(Нужно чтобы не выпадали при отображении всех ошибок)

`PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of Mixed_ShopService::updateProduct() should be compatible with Shop_ShopService::updateProduct(ShopProduct $product, $name, $description, $categoryID, $brandID, $model, $price, $priceold, $currencyID, $unit, $barcode, $discount, $preorderDiscount, $warranty, $hidden, $deleted, $avail, $availText, $syncable, $url, $image, $deleteImage, $collectionID, $width, $height, $length, $weight, $unitbox, $delivery, $payment, $divisibility, $userID, $denycomments, $notdiscount, $maxdiscount, $siteURL, $tax, $descriptionshort, $name1, $name2, $code1c, $codesupplier, $characteristics, $share, $seotitle, $seodescription, $seocontent, $seokeywords, $icon = false, $downloadFile = false, $deleteDownloadFile = false, $datelifefrom = false, $datelifeto = false, $articul = false, $suppliered = false) in /var/www/clients/client73/web146/web/modules/bubbone/api/services/Mixed_ShopService.class.php on line 3`

Comment: В php.ini есть error_reporting. Почитайте в документации какие значения принимает, поэкспериментируйте, определите настройки устраивающие Вас!

Comment: Правильный подход: убрать причины возникновения предупреждений.

Comment: У вас метод принимает на вход **55** (!) аргументов. Похоже, что путь только один -- все переписать ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev легко сказать) переписывать ничего не нужно, нужно разобраться можно ли его убрать) значит у товара 55ть полей в БД))

Answer (score 3):

Я так понимаю у вас наследование? 
Объявление функции `Mixed_ShopService::updateProduct()` 
должно с теми же аргументами как у `Shop_ShopService::updateProduct()`

Comment: Причина такого действия - есть в магазине стандартный продукт, в клиентской версии его переделали - унаследовали и изменили (добавили характеристик и тд), в итоге выпадает такой E_Strict. Базовый продукт изменять нельзя, а для потребностей клиента нужен продукт из дополнительными характеристиками(и аргументы необходимы естессно)

Comment: Вот и ищу можно ли как то правильно потушить ето предуприждение не подогнав два класса к одинаковым аргументам